# How to make copied buttons to function as same as the original button in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, function, clone

Before I ask more specifically, there's one assumption I have to make.
Every code has to be built in one html file.

So code underneath is what I implemented,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".clone").click(function(){
$(".cloner").clone().appendTo("#locations");
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="locations" class="tabcontent">
 <div class="cloner">
  <p>This is the paragraph</p>
  <button class="clone">clone</button>
  <div id="cloner2">
   <button class="clone">clone2</button>
   <div>
    <button class="clone">clone3</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do: 
1.) clone whole  into .
2.) Cloned buttons to function as well.

If I click "clone" button at very beginning, it will successfully clone whole  (so will clone2 and clone3).

Cloned  will have their own "clone", "clone2", and "clone3" buttons. I want those cloned buttons to function as same as the original buttons do but the way I coded do not make them to do that. Those cloned buttons do nothing while the original clone buttons still function.

Can you tell me how I can fix my code in order to make cloned buttons do as what I expected?

---

Also I have one extra question I came out as I wrote,

how can I clone only the "selected" section to be cloned?

For example, If I cloned once, resulting two . And I want to clone only second  by clicking buttons from second . My code wouldn't not work that way since I'm cloning whole every div with class="cloner" that clone button would clone every existing . How can I clone only the "selected" section to be cloned?

If you can answer only one of my questions, it's okay. I'll equally appreciate your answer.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *really* certain why you'd want to do this, but you can bind the click function to the actual button. That way the dynamically created content will also work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#locations').on('click', '.clone', function(){
//(parent container).on( event, object to bind, function
 
  $('.cloner:first').clone().appendTo("#locations").addClass('new');
});
  
  
// adding '.cloner:first' means it will 
// only clone the first instance, 
// rather than cloning clones of clones.....

});
```

```css
.new { background: #eee; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="locations" class="tabcontent">
 <div class="cloner">
  <p>This is the paragraph</p>
  <button class="clone">clone</button>
  <div id="cloner2">
   <button class="clone">clone2</button>
   <div>
    <button class="clone">clone3</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

As for cloning a specific part, you just need to target what you want cloned....

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#locations').on('click', '.clone', function(){
    $('.cloner p').clone().appendTo("#locations");
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="locations" class="tabcontent">
 <div class="cloner">
  <p>This is the paragraph</p>
  <button class="clone">clone</button>
  <div id="cloner2">
   <button class="clone">clone2</button>
   <div>
    <button class="clone">clone3</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```